# What are some resources to practice javascript while learning it?

Tags: self-learning, programming, resource-request, exercises, javascript

I’m looking for solved and unsolved assignments of JavaScript to practice.

My goals are both, practice javascript to learn to program as well as practice javascript to be able to design MERN applications and APIs. So, I need both fundamentals practice as well as advanced practice.

I’ve heard about codewars, leetcode but there are probably thousands of questions there. Is there a curated list of like 100 problems only that cover most concepts?

Is practicing Data structures and algorithms, numerical methods, computer graphics algorithms and Object oriented programming etc a good way to learn to program javascript?

I’m looking to practice js in console as well as with User Interface(building small web apps).

My research has got me this websites:

- https://www.jschallenger.com/
- https://exercism.org/tracks/javascript/exercises

It should be noted that I already have programming experience in university, I just could not excel at it like my friend. eg: I still have trouble to make stars printing programs which used to be a common exercise in the past.

I think programming fundamentals is all about looping so a practice material that helps me with looping concepts will be really helpful.

These are the things that I wish to practice:

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this idea "I think programming fundamentals is all about looping so a practice material that helps me with looping concepts will be really helpful." ? It is simply wrong.

Comment: Check my answer here https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/mern-which-textbook-to-use/6998#6998